# Django + JQuery .val() not setting

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I'm having some trouble setting the value of a JQuery object using .val().  I can get the initial value on page load, but when I change the inputs and do a page refresh, the values I'm getting are unchanged from initial load.  Here's some snippets:

HTML:

```
<table><tr>
<td><b>Employee:</b>
    <input id="employee" value="{{employee_display}}"/>
    <input id="id_prev_emp" class="prev_button" type='button' value='' />
    <input id="id_next_emp" class="next_button" type='button' value='' />
</td>
<td><b>Pay Period Start:</b>
    <input id="pay-period-start" value="{{pay_period_start}}" />
    <input id="prev_period" class="prev_button" type='button' value='' onclick='updateDates()' />
    <input id="next_period" class="next_button" type='button' value='' onclick='updateDates()' />
</td>
<td>
    <form action=?employee_id={{employee_id}}&pay_period_start={{pay_period_start}} method="POST">
    <input type="submit" value="Print" /></form>
</td>
</tr></table>
```

JS:

```
<script>
var employee_id="{{employee_id}}";
var pay_period_start="{{pay_period_start}}"
...
function updateDates(){
    $("#pay_period_start").val($("#pay-period-start").val());
}
```

The behavior I'm seeing isn't what I would expect it to be.
When I initially load the page, and click the 'Print' button, it goes into the Django code properly and pay_period_start is what it should be.  When I click the *prev_period* button, the page refreshes as it should and the text in pay-period-start is correct, but when I hit the 'Print' button, the Django code gets called and pay_period_start is the same as it was the first time.

I've tried doing something similar in a variety of ways, but think this is the closest I've gotten.  When debugging, I see the code hit a breakpoint set in updateDates(), but the .val() call isn't doing anything.  Running in the firefox console, **$("#pay_period_start").value** returns *undefined*.  After running the code from updateDates directly from the console, it still returns *undefined*

Any tips?

Comment: How do you expect Django to know about changes to input fields outside the form?

Comment: I used to have it in the form, but that didn't work either.  I'd expect {{pay_period_start}} to be a variable outside of the scope of just the form, so it shouldn't matter.

Comment: What's stranger is that when the prev/next emp buttons are pressed, clicking Print does pass in the correct employee id

Comment: Wait a second. You think `{{ pay_period_start }}` is a variable and can be manipulated using Javascript!?

Comment: Not necessarily manipulated by javascript, but a variable that changes on page load.  When the buttons are pressed, they call a refresh as well, and calling {{pay_period_start}} from firebug shows that it is changing, but when the form is submitted it is always the initial value.